# Formal definition of hash function

Tags: hash, definitions

I was reading through the classic CLRS with the intention of reviewing the hash tables theory, more specifically the hash function definition I just wanted a reference to quote.

I cannot find a formal definition given but I think it's fair to say a hash function (not univerisal) $h$ is a surjective map from a set of keys $K$ to a subset of integers $U$, for each $k \in K$ we define $h(k)$ to be the *hash value of $k$*. From the explanation given in CLRS it seems though this restriction on $U$ (be integers) might be too restrictive, however since I think the definition has to show some practical aspects I think this might be correct.

Can you either give me:
1. A paper/book with a formal definition
2. Confirm if my definition is correct?

Thank you

Comment: Not every informal concept has a standard formal definition.

Comment: I'm not sure why you require your function to be surjective.

Comment: I probably don't need surjection, since you have the notion of uniform hash. So a non uniform might imply you don't hit every value in the image space. So no formal definition then? Are there examples of hash functions whose values are not integers?

Comment: It is quite common to find hash functions whose output is a bitstring.

Comment: it's till an integer right? you wouldn't normally have a string for example, or some other strange types.

Comment: You may treat it as an integer. I think of it as a bitstring. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: That said, in cryptography there are formal definitions of hash functions. But that's not what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash function is used to map a set of keys to a subrange of the integers (it is used as an index into an array, in the end). So it must be (assuming zero based arrays, as in  C), $h \colon \mathcal{U} \to [0, m - 1]$ if $\mathcal{U}$ is the universe of keys.

Comment: So the image set is actually integers by definition, right? Any reference?

Comment: @user8469759, see how it is *used*.